# Java replaceAll regex for replacing Json string value

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I need a regex that does the following replacements:

```
"\"Id\":\"123Abc\",\"foo\":\"bar\"" -> "\"Id\":null,\"foo\":\"bar\"" (change value for only field \"Id\" into null)
"\"Id\":123" -> "\"Id\":null" (works for numbers too)
"\"Id\":null" -> "\"Id\":null" (if already null, do nothing)
"\"foo\":\"bar\"" - > "\"foo\":\"bar\"" (if \"Id\" not present, do nothing)
```

I came up with `\\\"Id\\\":([^]+)`, and on https://www.regextester.com it matches my string, but I tried turning it into Java code and nothing happens to the string.

```
str.replaceAll("\\\"Id\\\":([\\^]+)", "\\\"Id\\\":null");
```

Comment: Your character class for the id to be nullified may start with the caret sign followed by double quote.

Comment: Why aren't you using a JSON parser?

Comment: If `\"` is a delimiter, how do you check for an escaped delimiter ?

Comment: This `[^]` doesn't match anything.

Comment: The Java regex you need is this Find `("Id":)[^,]+(?=,)` replace `$1null`

Comment: @shmosel Not using a JSON parser because I only need to replace for this one field, and I believe parsing would be more expensive than regex in this case.

Comment: @onepiece But if the value of `Id` can be a string literal, that literal can contain escaped characters, so writing a regex is complex. What you should consider, more than performance, is **correctness**. A JSON parser will parse correctly. A regex may go wrong if there's some condition you forgot to check. Use a parser!! Don't waste more time on this, unless you learn thru *profiling* that performance is too slow. Beware premature optimizations, especially where optimizations may cause incorrect behavior.

Comment: To quote [Jamie Zawinski](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski): *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*

Comment: @sln I think  [^] matches any string except the empty string, thus regestester.com shows a match.

Answer (score 1):

The caret sign ( `^` ) has to be the first symbol inside the square brackets to have its inverting effect, so that `[^\]+` matches any character as long as it's not the backslash.

Also, the id string to be nullified is going to be present with double quotes so we have to match those as well and escape them : `\"[^\]+\"`

Moreover, Java needs its additional escaping so wee endup with `\\\"[^\\]+\\\"`

Finally , I would go with something like this :

```
str.replaceAll("\\\"Id\\\":\\\"([^\\]+)\\\"", "\\\"Id\\\":null");
```

Note that you may have to add optional space character depending on the input which are JSON compliant.

```
str.replaceAll("\\\"Id\\\"\s*:\s*\\\"([^\\]+)\\\"", "\\\"Id\\\"\s*:\s*null");
```

For references, you can read through https://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html